# Change caps-lock to control in virtual console on Ubuntu 17

Tags: command-line, keyboard, keyboard-layout

I'd like to change the Caps Lock behavior in virtual terminals (tty e.g. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>F3</kbd>) so it acts as a Control modifier. Ideally, I'd also like it to act as Escape when pressed alone, but just getting the Control behavior is proving difficult.

I'm running Ubuntu 17.04. I've read and tried numerous approaches to making this change, but none seem to apply to my system as described. I get the sense that systemd plays a part in this, but the particulars are unclear.

I've written a file, `caps_control.kmap`, that maps caps to control,

```
keymaps 0-255
keycode  58 = Control
```

If I run `loadkeys caps_control.kmap` from a virtual console, it works. Now I'd like to get it to load automatically upon boot/login/whatever...

I found references to using `/etc/rc.local` to do so, but my system has no such file, though it does have several directories like `/etc/rc0.d/`, `/etc/rc1.d/`, ...

It sounds like since Ubuntu 17 uses sytemd, I should use `localectl` to manage this sort of thing, but it's not clear to me how to do so. For example,

```
$ localectl status
   System Locale: LANG=en_US.UTF-8
       VC Keymap: n/a
      X11 Layout: us
       X11 Model: pc105
$ localectl list-keymaps
Couldn't find any console keymaps.
```

The man page for `localectl` mentions `/etc/locale.conf` and `/etc/vconsole.conf`, neither of which exist on my system.

I am totally at a loss. Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: Do you need this change to be active for all users or just your own?

Comment: @acer Either way would suit me, as I'm really the only user on this machine.

Comment: Hmm... You add a line in ~/.profile with `loadkeys caps_control.kmap` that would execute when you log in.

Comment: @acer Calling `loadkeys` from ~/.profile seems to be problematic. When I log in I get an error saying "Couldn't get a file descriptor referring to the console".

Answer (score 15, accepted):

To turn Caps Lock into an additional Ctrl modifier, which is also effective in tty consoles, open `/etc/default/keyboard` for editing and set:

```
XKBOPTIONS=ctrl:nocaps
```

If you already have `XKBOPTIONS` set, append `ctrl:nocaps` to its existing value using a comma for separator, e.g.:

```
XKBOPTIONS="terminate:ctrl_alt_bksp,ctrl:nocaps"
```

Should be effective after next reboot or issuing the `setupcon` command.

The option should be present when running `localectl status`:

```
$ localectl status | grep caps
     X11 Options: ctrl:nocaps
```

And in the X session, another way to verify that it's set is:

```
$ gsettings get org.gnome.desktop.input-sources xkb-options
['ctrl:nocaps']
```

Comment: another XKB option is `"ctrl:nocaps"`.  in X the difference is subtle: with the `ctrl` option, `xev` and other tools will see a `Control_L` symbol when the CapsLock key is pressed, while the `caps` option will still show the `Caps_Lock` keysym.  i'm not sure if that difference will translate to the virtual console's keymap.

Comment: @quixotic: Thanks for mentioning `ctrl:nocaps`. I added it to my answer.

Comment: Any idea why this isn't working for me? It's actually one of the first things I tried, and I like the approach. Unfortunately, it has no effect on my system.

Comment: @ivan: I just tested myself, and found that my first suggestion (`caps:ctrl_modifier`) is not effective in tty. However, for me (on 17.10) `ctrl:nocaps` is. Please see my edited answer.

Comment: @quixotic: It looks like the "subtle" difference you mentioned was essential with respect to tty consoles.

Comment: @GunnarHjalmarsson i'm not overly familiar with debian/ubuntu's method of translating XKB maps to console maps (it involves `ckbcomp`, i think?).  i didn't remember the `caps:ctrl_modifier` option you first mentioned, so looked it up to compare with the `ctrl:nocaps` i usually use, and thought the difference might be worth mentioning here.  glad it was helpful.

Comment: @quixotic: I don't know the topic well either. According to `man keyboard`, `setupcon` is used to configure the keyboard on the console.